# Security patch no longer supported android phone

Tags: security, rom, ota-update

I have a nextbit robin. Unfortunately they are no longer pushing out updates for them. Is there a way I can manually patch or am I better off installing a different ROM like cyanogenmod?

Comment: Is stock rom open source?

Comment: Yeah but not sure that compiling from source will work on a non-nexus phone

Answer (score 2):

If nextbit has open sourced it then you can build it and it will work. But this is an overkill for this purpose as in order to install you have to unlock bootloader and install a custom recovery.

So installing a custom rom look a better option.

Comment: I'm mostly security concerned. Any recommendations? Is lineage a good option?

Comment: Lineage is the best option for security purposes as they merge security patches very fast and they have a good reputation in devs.